# POST requests gives me an empty result

Tags: python, python-requests

For practicing purposes I'm trying to retrieve data from https://www.ruc.com.py/ by posting the number 1000000

At first it retrieved a "no access" message so I added headers and that solved it. But now it just brings a blank result, I was expecting to get a the name that corresponds with the input 1000000

This is my code:

```
import requests

headers = {
'referer': 'https://www.ruc.com.py/',
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.60 Safari/537.36',
'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'
}

num=str(1000000)

url = 'https://www.ruc.com.py/index.php/inicio/consulta_ruc'
response = requests.post(url , headers=headers, data=num)

print (response.text)
```

Comment: If you are trying to pass in a param and get a result, that looks like something that should be handled by a GET request. Not a POST. If there is any documentation to this API, that would be useful in figuring out what the endpoint really expects

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I go to the page and input manually 1000000 I can see in the Network tab that a Request Method: Post was sent. So I thought that might be the one to use. Sadly there is no documentation on this API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had a look into the network tab from the website and found out that the POST payload requires the search to be on the form field `buscar`

[image]

With this, just had to do this small change to your code to actually send the payload with the expected data structure:

```py
import requests

headers = {
'referer': 'https://www.ruc.com.py/',
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.60 Safari/537.36',
'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'
}

data={"buscar": 1000000}

url = 'https://www.ruc.com.py/index.php/inicio/consulta_ruc'
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)

print(response.json())
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked! You're a legend!

The code returns this:
[{'c_ruc': '1000000-3', 'c_razon_social': 'CAÑETE GONZALEZ, JUANA DEL CARMEN', 'b_facturador': 'N', 'n_grupo': None, 'd_fecha_obligatoriedad': None}]

If you don't mind a last question, would you know how can I retrieve only the data from 'c_razon_social'?

Comment: The return is just a list of dicts, you can iterate over the list and get the value for the key you want, for instance: `[item['c_razon_social'] for item in response.json()]` will list all the `c_razon_social` from the response. BTW, please accept the answer as correct if it worked for you :)